# Reverse engineering android native packer

Tags: c++, android, c, java

im trying to Reverse engineering an android app and the app have 4 folders in the **/data/data/{package}** folder

```
├───app_dexprotector
│       823517D25836B88F1C499C02370A047E.dat
│       823517D25836B88F1C499C02370A047E.dex
│
├───app_outdex
│       libdexprotector.bpqn57.12456.so
│
├───cache
└───lib
        libiconv.so
        libzbarjni.so
```

and all the files are the same except app_outdex file and when I start the app **app_dexprotector** folder will be modified after that a file will create on app_outdex then will delete immediately I create a copy of that file with **Termux** and **inotify-wait** and the interesting part is always the size of the file is different i searched the java code of the app and there is only an application class with a huge bytecode array and one native method like this :

```
    public static native int tfAHDD(Object obj, int I, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7, int i8);
```

the whole class is so long but it's only because of the byte array [this is the link of the class](https://github.com/osairon/android-native-packer/blob/master/ProtectedInitializer.java) my main questions are why the file has different sizes every time and why there are not other native methods? how the app will run this method and finally how can I analysis this .so file

Comment: Did you analyze the Java code with Apktool or dex2jar?

Comment: @Biswapriyo there is nothing to analyze only an application class and i upload it and you can see it too i can understand how the app loads classes without calling in java

Comment: The app is using DexProtector. Check this link : https://gameguardian.net/forum/topic/17029-how-to-get-the-decrypted-files-from-apk/

Answer (score 3):

You can't analyze native functions with a standard decompiler because native functions are not implemented in the Java Bytecode ([The Java Native Keyword and Methods](https://www.baeldung.com/java-native#:%7E:text=A%20native%20method%20is%20a,%5D%20native%20%5Breturn_type%5D%20method%20()%3B)).

You have to use common x86 disassemblers (Like IDA, JEB) to analyze the native functions.

At first, search for `System.loadLibrary` calls, to see which native library gets loaded (should be in a static block)

Once you found the native library you have to open it with a disassembler like IDA and go in **Exports** section:

[image]

Here you can see the implementation of your native functions.

Of couse you cannot expect java bytecode here, but only C pseudocode (if your disassebler supports it)

[image]